# Webgl/Three.js antialiasing issue

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm building the rectangle with the shadow and with transparency inside and I don't have issues with the antialiasing when the rectangle has a wide height and width, but when it comes to small values(<30px in my case) or 2d rotation(any angle) the geometry becomes to look not so nice and the antialiasing issues kick in.

So, this is how the rectangle 150x150x looks:
[150x150 rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7citG.png)

Same size, same rectangle, a small rotation added:
[150x150 rectangle && 2D rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cEif.png)

And when the size becomes lesser the quality of geometry has drastically fallen, 20x20 rectangle:
[20x20x rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymyRe.png)

Moving forward from this article for more accuracy and multi-aliasing enable I need to add an extension for derivatives to use 'fwidth' function and to define `linearstep(edge0, edge1, x)` as well.

In the three.js I don't need to enable an extension for derivatives, but in my glsl app I've enabled it by:
this.gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');

But still was unable to make the desired rectangle without antialiasing issues, if someone will be able to help here or share any helpful article about this issue - it would be really great.

My code: https://codepen.io/m_modesty/pen/PomemMm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, you should include any relevant code in your question. Links to external sources can and do die, and with them goes the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might research anisotropy, magnification filters, and mipmap. You might double the renderer resolution. You might accept that it's <30 pixels. Blur was cool, but Song 2 was <30 years ago. Threejs.org/examples has examples for three.js(.org).